# I am a beginner in Knime and using Random Forest

Tags: predictive-modeling, random-forest, knime

Within Knime how am I able to identify which of the variables have the best predictive power within my model. I have successful ran the model and assessed model accuracy, recall and precision but can not intuitively understand which of my variables were the most important within this model.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Random Forest, and many other tree based boosting algorithms, you can extract a quantitative value for all input variables call *Feature Importance*. This will give you a normalised value of how "important" the variable was in making decisions in the splits of the tree.